Getting CircularReferenceException while processing debug resources in Gradle
Encountering CircularReferenceException during project build in Android Studio, unsure if it's related to Gradle or dependencies.
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
--- :app:processDebugResources (*)
Exception is:-
org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
--- :app:processDebugResources (*)
This is my AndroidManifest.xml file :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.E_commerce_Application"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".orderConfirmation"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BILLInfo"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".payment"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".art"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".toys"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".skincare"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".kitchenware"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".clothes"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".food"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

This is my build.gradle.kts(:app) :-
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.e_commerce_application"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.e_commerce_application"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.1")
    implementation(project(":app"))

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
//    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")

}

I tired changing the version of buildtools. I refered this youtube tutorial.

The following line in your build.gradle dependencies block:
implementation(project(":app"))

will give rise to a circular dependency.

Thank you my issue is resolved now!
